# Cleanly iterating over a vector of mixed enum variants

Tags: vector, rust, enums, macros, either

I have code like the following:

```rust
enum Either<L, R> {
    Left(L),
    Right(R)
}

enum SomeMessageType {
    // ...
}


fn do_something<T>() {
    let data: Vec<Either<T, SomeMessageType>> = ...;

    // ...
}
```

I want to be able to iterate over the contents of `data` without explicitly specifying the `Either` types, because having to specify the `Either` everywhere makes the API ugly and annoying to work with. The generic type `T` in `do_something` will always be an enum variant, I just don't know if it's possible to express that in Rust's generic types. Ideally, I'd like to be able to write something like:

```rust
fn do_something<...>() {
    let data = ...;
    matching_iterator!(data, {
        SomeMessageType::... => ...
        T::SomeVariant => ...
    });
}
```

I have tried writing a macro like this already:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! check_mail {
    ( $data:expr, { $( $pattern:pat => $handler:block )+ } ) => {
        {
            use $crate::build_pattern;
                for data in $data.iter() {
                    if let $crate::build_pattern!($( $pattern )+) = message {
                        $( $handler )+
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! build_pattern {
    ( $pattern:pat ) => {
        Either::Right($pattern)
    };

    ( $pattern:pat ) => {
        Either::Left($pattern)
    };
}
```

but obviously this code won't compile, much less run. My intuition says I should put a differentiator of some sort at the start of each pattern, to make it easier to write the macro, but I haven't been able to get that to work. Each attempt generates the match arm code wrong, with all the matches at the start and then all the handler blocks at the end, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you show the correct Rust code that you're trying to avoid having to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to have some way to differentiate `Left` and `Right` patterns I used `;` here.

Also you can't match on variants of a generic cause it might be any type and might not even have them.

```rust
fn do_something() {
    use Either::*;
    let data = vec![Right(T::SomeVariant), Left(SomeMessageType::Good)];
    matching_iterator!(data,
        SomeMessageType::Good => {}
        ;
        T::SomeVariant => {}
        T::SomeOtherVariant => {}
    );
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! matching_iterator {
    ( $data:expr, $($lpattern:pat => $lhandler:block)+; $($rpattern:pat => $rhandler:block)+ ) => {
        {
            for data in $data.iter() {
                match data {
                    $(Either::Left($lpattern) => $lhandler)+
                    $(Either::Right($rpattern) => $rhandler)+
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This is what I was struggling to figure out! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but you can probably hide that with one or more callbacks ?

i.e.:

```rust
fn do_something<T, F, H>(f: F, h: H)
    where F: Fn(T) -> (),
          H: Fn(SomeMessageType) -> ()
{
    let data = ...;
    data.for_each(|either| {
        match either {
            Either::Left(t) => f(t),
            Either::Right(r) => h(r),
        }
    })
}
```

Which you can then call with whichever handler you want for both types:

```rust
do_something(
    |t| { match t { MyEnum::Some => ... }}, 
    |msg| { println!("I received this message: {}", msg); }
);
```

Would that solve your problem, as the `Either` implementation is hidden in `do_something`